# Перевод маркера чтения QByteArray через QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

Есть такая конструкция:

```
QDataStream stream(&source, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

где `source` это `QByteArray`

Я хочу переместить маркер чтения на определенную позицию, как я могу это сделать?

В документации нашел только метод `skipRawData(int len)`, но как я понимаю он пропускается некоторое количество байт от текущей позиции. Есть ли способ установить маркер на определенную позицию?

Comment: вызвать сначала device()->reset(), а потом skipRawData в нужную позицию?

Comment: Нет доступа к девайсу. Только байтовый массив и стрим для управления им.

Comment: функцию device надо вызвать у stream, я думал, это очевидно